# What issues would a setup like this cause? (Cisco POE switch -> unmanaged gigabit switch -> HP JD483B -> MSM313)

Tags: networking, poe

What issues would a setup like this cause? 
    Cisco POE switch -> unmanaged gigabit switch -> HP JD483B (POE injector) -> MSM313

I need to add a device for a short period of time. Would I need something besides the HP JD483B?

Thanks!